# How to display only needed reference in the beamer?

Tags: beamer, citing

I want to cite in a certain slide in my beamer, but the slide display all references which contains references that doesn't belong to this slide, how to solve this problem?

For example, in the following picture, only the first reference is truly I cited, the other two are from other slides.

My Latex codes are as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title[Multi-Sensor Fusion]{Multi-Sensor Fusion}


 \author{Wangyan Li}% Your name
 \institute[USST] 
{ \\
 \medskip
\textit{{\tt
 wangyan$\_$li@icloud.com}} 
 }
  \date{\today}


 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
 \end{frame}

 \section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{History}
 At the beginning of 1970s, the U.S. navy merged data about Soviet naval movements at data fusion centers, the result turned out to be much accurate than using data from single sonar \cite{friedman2001seapower}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{article,book} 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Optimal Information Fusion}

\begin{itemize}

\item  Independent Estimates  \cite{Sijs2012}\\
\item  Correlated Estimates \cite{Sun2004}\\
\item  Unknown Covariance  
\end{itemize}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{article,book} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> full.bib

```
@book{friedman2001seapower,
title={Seapower as Strategy: Navies and National Interests},
author={Friedman, Norman},
year={2001},
publisher={Naval Institute Press}
}
```

> article.bib

```
@article{Sun2004,
 doi = {10.1016/j.automatica.2004.01.014},
 url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2004.01.014},
 year  = {2004},
 month = jun,
 publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
 volume = {40},
 number = {6},
 pages = {1017--1023},
 author = {ShuLi Sun and ZiLi Deng},
 title = {Multi-sensor optimal information fusion {K}alman filter},
 journal = {Automatica}
}

 @article{Sijs2012,
 doi= {10.1016/j.automatica.2012.05.077},
 url= {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.automatica.2012.05.077},
 year = {2012},
 month= aug,
 publisher= {Elsevier $\lbrace$BV$\rbrace$},
 volume= {48},
 number= {8},
 pages= {1874--1878},
 author= {Joris Sijs and Mircea Lazar},
 title= {State fusion with unknown correlation: Ellipsoidal intersection},
 journal= {Automatica}
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Then, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you consulted the [chapterbib](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite) and [bibunits](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits/) packages?

Comment: I used `bibunits` packages, it works, thanks you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follows the Mico's suggestion, I used `bibunits` packages, it works.

First, put the following codes at the beginning of the document,

```
\usepackage{bibunits}  
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}
\defaultbibliography{book,article}
\defaultbibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

Second, replace the original texts as:

```
\begin{frame}{History}
\begin{bibunit}[plain]
At the beginning of 1970s, the U.S. navy merged data about Soviet naval movements at data fusion centers, the result turned out to be much accurate than using data from single sonar \cite{friedman2001seapower}.
\putbib
\end{bibunit}
```

Then, it works out, like,
[image]

That is what I wanted!!!

Comment: Why didn't you ask Mico to write an answer?

Comment: Yes, I should.  Next time I know how to do it.

Comment: Sounds fair enough ;).